# Can someone help me increase the length of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, junit

Basically, I need to create a new array (newList) one element bigger than the old array (PredatorList). The only thing I'm meant to edit from the code below is the stuff within the increaseArray method. I am not allowed to edit the method name/signature. I have to perform a Junit test on it but I keep getting an error and I don't know why. My code so far:

```
public class Pack {
/**
* Predator list.   This contains the list of all Predators. 
* The list should never contain a null in the middle and should never have more than one 
* blank at the end (eg a null).
*/
private Predator[] PredatorList = new Predator[0];

/**
* Increase the array by one.  You will need to create a new array one element 
* bigger than the old array. 
* No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method
* My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 3
* 
*/
private void increaseArray() {
   int increment = 1;
   Predator[] newList = new Predator[PredatorList.length + increment];
   for (int i = 0; i < PredatorList.length; i++) {
         newList[i] = PredatorList[i];
         }
   }

}
```

I have a PackTest class that shows this but I don't really know how to read it.

```
public void testAddPredator2()  
{  
  Pack list = null;  
  //add normal Predator  
  list = buildTestSet();  
  //System.out.println("->"+list.getNumberOfPredators());  
  int before = list.getNumberOfPredators();  
  list.addPredator(new Predator("Pony",100,100,5));  
  int after = list.getNumberOfPredators();  
  //System.out.println("->"+list.getNumberOfPredators());  
  assertEquals(before+1,after);  
  countOfSuccesfulTests++;  
}
```

Any help would be great. Cheers!

Comment: What error are you getting? I see that you need add `PredatorList = newList;` at the end of increaseArray to assign your newlist to instance variable.

Comment: You know, I think that whenever I see a SO post that says "I'm getting an error", I'm going to respond with "I'm giving you an answer".  If the poster won't tell us what the error is, I don't need to tell them what the answer is.  :)

Comment: The problem is, I'm not sure what the error is because I can't sense of how Junit works. There is a PackTest class that shows ...(I've placed it into the original question above)

Comment: JUnit does give you output. If you have a test that fails because it's testing that two values are equal, and they aren't, it should tell you what line the failed assertion is on, and you can use that to see what values are failing the test.  That's useful information for us (if you also show us the test so that we can see what's happening).  If you can't get that info from JUnit, something's configured wrong or else you just haven't found where your IDE is displaying it, or something.

Comment: testAddPredator fails on line: assertEquals(before+1,after); and the Failure Trace says AssertionError: expected:<-9998> but was:<-9999>

Comment: Hint: variable names go camelCase in Java.

Comment: And it doesn't wonder you when your **initilaized** list has -9999 elements?! Hint: step back, and start with a test for an empty list. That should return 0 for size. And then you write a test that checks your *pack* has the length that you expect after running your `buildTestSet()`. And if you want us to help, then you better post the code for that list/build methods, too!

Answer (score 1):

You create a new list but don't assign it to the field with the original list afterwards.

```
this.PredatorList = newList;
```

is missing.